# heroku-like workflow on personal server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ubuntu, workflow, heroku

I'm trying to set up a server with pure-git workflow similar to [heroku](http://heroku.com). I *don't* need help setting up git, but for informative purposes, I'm using [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite). I'd like to (somehow) write custom hooks in the operating system (Ubuntu) of this system so that, when it receives a push on a particular branch, it performs all the operators heroku does (starting Rack, Mongrel, Apache (for static serving pages in my case), etc.

Can someone point me towards a resource to do this or at least get started? A google search didn't really seem to help...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It sounds like you want to execute arbitrary functionality at a certain point in your Git workflow. Git hooks are the way to go.

If you look in any Git repo (inside the `.git` folder), you'll see a `hooks` folder. Inside it there are a number of example hook files with different names. Based on your explanation above, you want to edit the `post-receive` hook file, since that will be called immediately after a new ref has been updated in your remote repo (resulting from a push from a local one). For more info, read [the official documentation on hooks](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) or read this perhaps [more approachable explanation](http://progit.org/book/ch7-3.html).

You can put any shell commands you want in a hook file. Change the filename from `post-receive.sample` to simply `post-receive`, add the commands you need to start Rack, Mongrel, Apache, etc., then make the file executable with a quick `chmod +x post-receive` and you're all set.

Comment: I'm a little bummed that my answer wasn't chosen, since the updated version includes a link to git-deploy, which does exactly what the author was asking ("pure git workflow similar to Heroku" -- and an explanation of how it works in the comments), but I shall give you an upvote, as well.  :)

Comment: Git-deploy looks like an interesting project, but it does seem to have a Ruby + Capistrano emphasis. I think the main drive of seth.vargo's question was, how does one have actions automatically triggered based on Git activity. In that light, having basic knowledge about Git hooks is more generally applicable. Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 19):

Have you looked at [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki)?  From wiki:

> Capistrano is a utility and framework
>   for executing commands in parallel on
>   multiple remote machines, via SSH. It
>   uses a simple Domain Specific Language
>   borrowed in part from the tool rake.
>   Rake is similar to make in the C world
>   and allows you to define tasks, which
>   may be applied to machines in certain
>   roles. It also supports tunneling
>   connections via some gateway machine
>   to allow operations to be performed
>   behind VPNs and firewalls.
>
> Capistrano
>   was originally designed to simplify
>   and automate deployment of web
>   applications to distributed
>   environments, and originally came
>   bundled with a set of tasks designed
>   for deploying Rails applications. The
>   deployment tasks are now (as of
>   Capistrano 2.0) opt-in and require
>   clients to explicitly put "load
>   ‘deploy’" in their recipes.

It's not based on any sort of commit or post hooks, although I'm sure if you really needed that, then you would be able to find some example recipes to do something like that.

**Update:** Maybe [git-deploy](https://github.com/mislav/git-deploy) (based on Capistrano) is what you want:

> A tool to install useful git hooks on your remote repository to enable push-based, Heroku-like deployment on your host.

Comment: that's completely irrelevant. I don't need to know how to deploy the app, I need to know how to use custom hooks to automatically start these processes whenever the app is pushed via git

Comment: You can create tasks in Capistrano to control the starting and stopping of your application server(s).  So no, not *completely* irrelevant.

Comment: Yea, but I can also do that with simple rake or even a bash script

Comment: The only difference between what @seth wants, and what @galador is offering, is that @seth wants to use nothing but git from his dev box.

Comment: Which is how my "update" link works (git-deploy).  You run the setup once to initialize things, and then you can do something like `git push origin production` (`production` being whatever branch you want to be auto-deployed).  It then uses lovely git hooks on the server side to do deployment actions automatically (*which* actions are determined by what has changed in your code, and are described in detail in the "Deployment" section of the github page).

Comment: As of about a year ago, git-deploy isn't dependent on Capistrano anymore. I found it to be the easiest way to setup this style of workflow without introducing additional complexity or dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

I just uncovered https://github.com/mislav/git-deploy, which is EXACTLY what I wanted. I'm going to leave the other answer as "correct" (since it was the best at the time), but I'm using git-deploy now :)

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar setup where the master branch is automatically deployed as staging using capistrano on git push. Production is manually deployed from the production branch.

The setup require that you use `set :deploy_via, :remote_cache` in `deploy.rb` to have a local cache copy on the server. This is to be able to run capistrano with the latest configuration if is has been changed since last deploy.

`post-receive` hook script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
        if [ "$ref" = "refs/heads/master" ] ; then
                echo "Master branch pushed, deploying to staging"
                # seams to be set to "." for hooks, unset to make things more normal
                unset GIT_DIR
                # deploy path, where "current", "releases", "shared" etc are
                DEPLOYDIR="/home/user/deploy/staging"
                # default path for :deploy_via :remote_cache is shared/cached-copy
                cd "$DEPLOYDIR/shared/cached-copy"
                # update cache to pushed revision, will be done by capistrano too
                git fetch origin && git fetch --tags origin && git reset --hard "$newrev"
                # load rvm
                source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
                rvm use 1.9.2
                # make sure correct gems are installed
                # this will also create a .bundle directory
                bundle install --gemfile Gemfile --path "$DEPLOYDIR/shared/bundle" --deployment --without development test
                # run capistrano
                # if you use deploy:migrations instead of deploy you should probably add
                # after "deploy:migrations", "deploy:cleanup"
                # to your deploy.rb
                bundle exec cap staging deploy:migrations
        fi
done
```

A simpler setup without `:remote_cache` is also possible but it will run capistrano with the previous (currently deployed) configuration and seams to be a bit more fragile.

`post-receive` hook script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev ref
do
        if [ "$ref" = "refs/heads/master" ] ; then
                echo "Master branch pushed, deploying to staging"
                # seams to be set to "." for hooks, unset to make things more normal
                unset GIT_DIR
                source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
                rvm use 1.9.2
                cd /home/user/deploy/staging/current && bundle exec cap staging deploy:migrations  
        fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend checking out [GitHub:progrium/dokku](https://github.com/progrium/dokku), it's based on [Docker](https://www.docker.io/) technology and really easy to setup and use.

If you're also looking for cloud provider, I recommend [DigitalOcean](http://digitalocean.com) since they support Dokku out of the box! Checkout their [community documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tags/dokku) for more information.

Your workflow will be very much similar to Heroku: ([Full Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-use-the-digitalocean-dokku-application))

1. Setup Dokku Server (Your personal Heroku) and your public key
2. Configure your domain to point *.DOMAIN.com to Dokku Server
3. Add Git Remote to your repo: `git remote add myheroku dokku@DOMAIN.com:your-app`
4. Push code to Dokku server: `git push myheroku master`
5. Checkout `http://your-app.DOMAIN.com`

Also if you want to have different sub-domain or full-domain assign to your app, you can install [Dokku Domain Plugin](https://github.com/wmluke/dokku-domains-plugin) and simply do specify domain to your-app: `dokku domains:set your-app NEWDOMAIN.com`

It's worth mentioning new project called [Flynn](https://flynn.io/) [GitHub: flynn/flynn](https://github.com/flynn/flynn) which comes with more features than Dokku. Read history behind Flynn and Dokku [here...](http://progrium.com/blog/2014/02/06/the-start-of-the-age-of-flynn/)

Comment: Also You need to set up 0.0.0.0 as hostname for RoR app.